# Questions specific to software on a platform

Tags: discussion, tags, title

I broke what I consider to be a cardinal rule based on previous experience with the community by asking a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956171/compiling-c-sharp-projects-with-vscode-on-ubuntu) while including tags in the question title. As much as I tried, I found that was unable to provide an effective title without breaking said "rule" because it otherwise would not effectively distinguish the problem. I'm sure I'm not the only one that has been faced with this issue given the cross-platform nature of our topic (i.e. programming).

My primary question is, does my experience reflect the general opinion of the community? If not then I must've been led to misunderstand the intent of the "rule" as I knew it.

If this is in-fact something that moderators rightfully look for in questions then: do you have any recommendations for titles without including the tags in the title?

This repetition bugs me but I'd gladly stop tampering with it if I knew that it wasn't going to cause problems.

Comment: Roughly 60% of all questions break this "cardinal rule".  The cardinal retired, don't fret over it.

Comment: Note that title of linked post is sentence that happen to include tags, not tags wrapping collection of words... I doubt you broke a rule that way. "C#.VS.Ubuntu. project files not compile not working" would be title that includes tags.

Comment: Bad title: "Compiling projects with VSCode [c#] [ubuntu]". Good title: "Compiling C# projects with VSCode on Ubuntu"

Comment: @AakashM: I would dispute "good". But less bad, and no obvious way to enhance without knowing the whole post, sure.

Comment: The best title is one that: is a english sentence; and describes the problem you are facing in a succinct manner. As long as you follow both precepts you are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title is perfectly fine. It defines both the subject and some context. This way, people who know something about it can quickly find your question.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with that imo.

The don't-include-tags-into-the-title "rule" (if it's a rule, which it imo isn't) is meant for titles like: *"[C#] Compiling projects with VSCode"* or *"C# - Compiling projects with VSCode"*. In this case, the extra prefix is useless as (a) StackOverflow already prefixes the question with the primary tag in the title of the page and (b) the tags are clearly visible when viewing the question or a list of questions.